# Skip authorization in Spring service for internal service to service calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring layered architecture, performing authorization of the requests in the service classes. One service could look like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    public void findOne(Long id) {
        assertPrivilege("READ");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, `assertPrivilege()` uses the `SecurityContextHolder` to obtain a list of `GratedAuthority` objects. Putting the authorization logic into services, the controllers don´t have to worry about that - also when calling multiple services from one controller.

The problem is that all other services cannot access that method now, unless authorized. However, there are some threads (schedulers for example) which exactly call that method at some point without having an `Authentication` object ready. In some cases, if it is the same thread, the `SecurityContext` will also return the current authentication.

Now, how to refactor this logic to achieve the other internal threads to call the method without authorization. Is a design change needed, possible a second wrapper class like `SomeService` (no authorization) and `SomeClientService` (with authorization)? Another possibility would be to access the repositories directly.

Comment: would it be possible to create auth context from service where you want to call another service which requires authorization? I do this in my project as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER') or hasRole('ROLE_EDITOR') or #id == authentication.principal.username")` instead of method, [see tutorial, there are many of them](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security).

Generally, your business logic should not be mixed with security framework - it's why there are `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` - developer should be able define user access independently from business logic - it's two different requirements.

There are no easy way to disable spring security for one user (inner call, external app etc.), also it's not recommended (bugs etc.), you can create special role for external app or use [Concurrency Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/concurrency.html) to perform inner call in behalf of user.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy service approach seems to be the easiest thing to do, as you don't need to move authorization logic out of this layer. Managing authorization as an aspect would be the key for that solution. Otherwise, you can always manage these checks directly in the controllers, so every endpoint handles it according to the type of client it was designed to be used by.